# Python passing list into a function and return back to main

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am taking 3 values from the users. Number1, Number2 and Power, considering Number1 and Number2 as a range of a list. Then I am trying to pass the list of the of numbers into a function as a parameter along with the power value as another parameter. Using the pow function to calculate the powers of each of the numbers in the list using a for loop. I want to store the results in the same list which was passed into this function and return back to the main function and print there. Now the question is, I assume i am trying the wrong approach since the output is not as expected. I declared another list (results) and store all the power results from the numbers list into it. Then asigned the results list to numbers list, so as to copy all the values in it. Now when i return the numbers list and print in the main function, it still shows the same values which were in the numbers list before it was sent to the function. Though when i try to print the list inside the function, it gives correct output. How am I wrong, and how should i correct it?

```
def powerList(numbers, power):
   print("In the function")
   print(numbers)
   print("Calculating powers")

   result = []
   for x in range(len(numbers)):
      result.append(pow(numbers[x], power))

   numbers = result
   return(numbers)

def main():
   n1 = int(input("Input number1: "))
   n2 = int(input("Input number2: "))
   power =  int(input("Input power: "))
   numbers = [x for x in range(n1,n2+1)]
   print(numbers)
   print("Passed to the function powerList")
   powerList(numbers, power)
   print(numbers)

main()
```

Comment: You have to realize that `numbers = result` line in `powerList` function does not do what you think. It replaces the **local** variable `numbers` but it does not affect `numbers` variable outside `powerList` function. So to make it work simply do what Vignesh Kalai suggested.

Comment: Do you want to *change the original list*, or *create a new list*?

Comment: the original list. I followed Vignesh Kalai and it seemed to work.

Comment: No, that answer creates **a new list** (initially named `result`) in `powerList`, returns it and merely reassigns the name `numbers` within `main` to the new list. This doesn't change the list that `numbers` originally referred to; you can see this by adding e.g. `print(id(numbers))` before and after the line `numbers = powerList(numbers, power)`.

Comment: you are correct. The id numbers are different. I tried doing it your way, it also worked and then the id numbers output was similar. Btw what does id function do here?

Comment: See e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id - if two names give the same `id` value at the same time, they point to the same exact object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the function to *mutate* the argument list, do so explicitly and (by convention) `return None`, e.g.:

```
def power_list(numbers, power):  # note PEP-8 naming style
    for index, item in enumerate(numbers):
        numbers[index] = pow(item, power)
    # no explicit return is equivalent to 'return None'
```

which replaces the content of `numbers` one element at a time, or:

```
def power_list(numbers, power):
    numbers[:] = [pow(number, power) for number in numbers]
```

which uses a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create a new list, then overwrites the content of the original with the new values. In use, with either version:

```
>>> lst = range(5)
>>> lst
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> power_list(lst, 2)
>>> lst
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Comment: thanks. it worked correctly and was technically a better answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try getting the returned object:

```
numbers = powerList(numbers, power)
```

Another thing that you can do is return the function output directly without saving it to another variable:

```
return powerList(numbers, power)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning numbers but not getting the return values:
check this statement in the fucntion :
**numbers = powerList(numbers, power)**

```
def powerList(numbers, power):
   print("In the function")
   print(numbers)
   print("Calculating powers")

   result = []
   for x in range(len(numbers)):
      result.append(pow(numbers[x], power))

   numbers = result
   return(numbers)

def main():
   n1 = int(input("Input number1: "))
   n2 = int(input("Input number2: "))
   power =  int(input("Input power: "))
   numbers = [x for x in range(n1,n2+1)]
   print(numbers)
   print("Passed to the function powerList")
   numbers = powerList(numbers, power)
   print(numbers)

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, lists are references, so, you could change list content inside a function and the list will be changed across the main function:

```
In [7]: def foo(l):
   ...:     l.append(42)
   ...:     

In [8]: xs = [1, 2, 3]

In [9]: foo(xs)

In [10]: xs
Out[10]: [1, 2, 3, 42]
```

However, reassigning the list will not affect the main list:

```
In [11]: def bar(l):
   ....:     l = [42]
   ....:     

In [12]: bar(xs)

In [13]: xs
Out[13]: [1, 2, 3, 42]
```

Instead, you could return the new list:

```
In [14]: def baz(l):
   ....:     return l + [3.14]
   ....: 

In [15]: baz(xs)
Out[15]: [1, 2, 3, 42, 3.14]
```

And, of course, assign it to another variable:

```
In [16]: new_list = baz(xs)

In [17]: print(new_list)
[1, 2, 3, 42, 3.14]
```